# How to tell if a Python modules I being reload()ed from within the module

Tags: python, reload, python-module

When writing a Python module, is there a way to tell if the module is being imported or reloaded?

I know I can create a class, and the `__init__()` will only be called on the first import, but I hadn't planning on creating a class.  Though, I will if there isn't an easy way to tell if we are being imported or reloaded.

Comment: `__init__()` is called when objects are created.  If your import creates objects, your code is actually doing things in a very bad way.  Please provide some code so you can see -- and fix -- your problem.

Comment: i haven't created anything yet- i wondering if i put defs in a file named, MyMod.py and import MyMod, how can MyMod tell if it was `import MyMod` or `reload(MyMod)`

Comment: What?  defs have nothing to do with creation of objects and invocation of the `__init__` special method.  What on earth are you talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation for `reload()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reload) actually gives a code snippet that I *think* should work for your purposes, at least in the usual case. You'd do something like this:

```
try:
    reloading
except NameError:
    reloading = False # means the module is being imported
else:
    reloading = True # means the module is being reloaded
```

What this really does is detect whether the module is being imported "cleanly" (e.g. for the first time) or is overwriting a previous instance of the same module. In the normal case, a "clean" import corresponds to the `import` statement, and a "dirty" import corresponds to `reload()`, because `import` only really imports the module once, the first time it's executed (for each given module).

If you somehow manage to force a subsequent execution of the `import` statement into doing something nontrivial, or if you somehow manage to import your module for the first time using `reload()`, or if you mess around with the importing mechanism (through the `imp` module or the like), all bets are off. In other words, don't count on this *always* working in every possible situation.

P.S. The fact that you're asking this question makes me wonder if you're doing something you probably shouldn't be doing, but I won't ask.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import os
>>> os.foo = 5
>>> os.foo
5
>>> import os
>>> os.foo
5
```

Comment: if you `reload(os)` is there a way to tell (from within os) if it had been `import`ed or `reload()`ed

Comment: I misunderstood the question. See David Zaslavsky's answer. 

In general you don't really want to be maintaining state within your module - it's usually considered bad practice.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024799/python-object-persistence-over-re-execs